# why am I getting run time error:StringIndexOutOfBounds?

Tags: java, runtime-error

Doing my AP Computer Science homework right now but I am stuck with run-time errors. Does anyone know what is wrong with my code?
The program was working fine on Dr.Java but it shows run-time error on my website tester in edhesive...

```
class Main{

 public static void main (String str[]) throws IOException {
   Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

   System.out.println("Please enter a tweet:");
   String tweet = scan.nextLine();

   int hash = 0;
   int attr = 0;
   int link = 0;
   int ch = 0;
   if(tweet.length()>140)
   {
   System.out.println("Excess Characters: " + (tweet.length() - 140 ));
   }

   else
   {
   tweet=tweet.toLowerCase();
   System.out.println("Length Correct");


   for(ch=0; ch<tweet.length(); ch++)
   {
   if(tweet.charAt(ch) == '#' && ((ch++)<=(tweet.length())) && (tweet.charAt(ch++)!=' ' && tweet.charAt(ch++)!='\t'))
   {
   hash++;
   }
   if(tweet.charAt(ch) == '@' && ((ch++)<=(tweet.length())) && (tweet.charAt(ch++)!=' ' && tweet.charAt(ch++)!='\t'))
   {
   attr++;
   }
   if(tweet.charAt(ch) == 'h' && ((ch + 7)<=(tweet.length())))
   {
   String a = new String("http://");
   String sub = new String(tweet.substring(ch, ch + 7)); 
     if (sub.equals(a))
     {link++;}
   }



   }

   System.out.println("Number of Hashtags: " + hash);
   System.out.println("Number of Attributions: " + attr);
   System.out.println("Number of Links: " + link);

   }

}
}
```

Comment: What boolean does `(ch++)<=(tweet.length())` return when a tweet only consists of `#`, `@` or `h`? The next check after that - `tweet.charAt(ch++) != ' '` - will throw the exception your receiving. `tweet.charAt(ch++)` throws the exception.

Comment: what kind of input String got run-time error? Could you tell me more detail? When I run your program, it is work. Maybe IDE problem ...

Comment: @Alice try running the program and only entering `#` or `@`.

Comment: @Yijia Jin  Could you specify what the requirement is. tweet.charAt(ch++) is throwing the runtime exception.

Answer (score 1):

Because of `ch++` the value of ch is getting incremented after checking this condition `(ch++)<=(tweet.length())`.

Explanation :

```
if(tweet.charAt(ch) == '#' && ((ch++)<=(tweet.length())) && (tweet.charAt(ch++)!=' ' && tweet.charAt(ch++)!='\t'))
   {
   hash++;
   }
```

For above code there are 4 conditions (for i=0):

1. tweet.charAt(ch) ch = 0
2. ((ch++)<=(tweet.length())) ch = 0, but ch++ so the value will be increamented after the condition check.
3. (tweet.charAt(ch++) ch=1 (becuase of Point No. 2)
4. tweet.charAt(ch++) ch = 2 (for the same reason).

Try this:

```
class Main{

 public static void main (String str[]) throws IOException {
   Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

   System.out.println("Please enter a tweet:");
   String tweet = scan.nextLine();

   int hash = 0;
   int attr = 0;
   int link = 0;
   int ch = 0;
   if(tweet.length()>140)
   {
   System.out.println("Excess Characters: " + (tweet.length() - 140 ));
   }

   else
   {
   tweet=tweet.toLowerCase();
   System.out.println("Length Correct");


   for(ch=0; ch<tweet.length(); ch++)
   {
   if(tweet.charAt(ch) == '#' && ((ch+1)<(tweet.length())) && (tweet.charAt(ch+1)!=' ' && tweet.charAt(ch+1)!='\t'))
   {
   hash++;
   }
   if(tweet.charAt(ch) == '@' && ((ch+1)<(tweet.length())) && (tweet.charAt(ch+1)!=' ' && tweet.charAt(ch+1)!='\t'))
   {
   attr++;
   }
   if(tweet.charAt(ch) == 'h' && ((ch + 7)<(tweet.length())))
   {
   String a = new String("http://");
   String sub = new String(tweet.substring(ch, ch + 7)); 
     if (sub.equals(a))
     {link++;}
   }



   }

   System.out.println("Number of Hashtags: " + hash);
   System.out.println("Number of Attributions: " + attr);
   System.out.println("Number of Links: " + link);

   }

}
}
```

Comment: Your code fails for tweets of length 1, for instance a tweet with just `#` or `@` will throw an index out of bounds exception. When `ch = 0` then `ch + 1 <= tweet.length` and `tweet.charAt(ch + 1)` throws an exception, since the length of the tweet is 1.

Comment: Yes. That works well. Turns out I was confused about ch++ and ch+1 but now it's quite clear. Thanks a lot:)

Comment: I think it solved the problem then you should make my answer as correct. see : http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235